# calling parent methods from overriden class in C#

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have the following code:

```
class ClassA
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(1); // when called from ClassB, it calls DoSomething from ClassA with an infinite recursion
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething(int someInt)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(1);
    }
    public override void DoSomething(int someInt)
    {
         base.DoSomething(someInt);

        // do something
    }
}

class Program
{
    void someMethod()
    {
        ClassB instance = new ClassB();
        instance.DoSomething(); // stack overflow caused by infinite recursion
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I call `ClassB.DoSomething();` and it calls `base.DoSomething(someInt);` I want the parent class which ClassB is derived to call ClassA's method instead of the overriden one.

Is there a way to do this in a clean way without copying/pasting repeated code?

Comment: When I run your code it works fine -- no stack overflow. Are you sure you pasted in the code you're really running?

Comment: @Jon B it is a representation of my class. Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/wiJnGbpN I didn't want to paste it as it was long, and I already found the problem. I just want to know how to call an overriden method from the base class.

Comment: There is no magic needed to call an overriden method. Just call the method as you normally would. Try it!

Comment: That is not my problem, I want to call the overriden method from the base class. When I call the method from the base class, it calls the overriden method instead of the base class method (which is the one I want to call)

Comment: @Nick Bray I can't call base.DoSomething() from ClassA as ClassA is the base class

Comment: Oh... I think I see what you're saying. You might want to use hiding here instead. You would *not* have a virtual method, and the derived class would use the `new` keyword to "hide" the base method. Kind of a dangerous approach, though...

Comment: @JonB The problem there is that you rely on the child class to not override the method.  If you're going to do that you may as well just not mark it `virtual` in the first place.  If it needs to be virtual then see my answer for a more effective way around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the base class like so:

```
class ClassA
{
    public virtual void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomethingHelper(1); // when called from ClassB, it calls DoSomething from ClassA with an infinite recursion
    }

    public virtual void DoSomething(int someInt)
    {
        DoSomethingHelper(someInt);
    }

    private void DoSomethingHelper(int someInt)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

By refactoring out the entire method into a private method you provide a means to call the current class' definition of the method while still providing a virtual method for the child class to access.

Answer (score 0):

When you override the virtual method you can't call it without the base keyword, so you cannot cal if from that class.  You can try using what Jon B said and use method shadowing instead of overriding.

```
class ClassA
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(1); 
    }

    public void DoSomething(int someInt)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("a");
    }
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public new void DoSomething()
    {
        DoSomething(1);
    }

    public new void DoSomething(int someInt)
    {
        base.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that the base class can't guarantee that no children will override the method (unless the method isn't virtual).

Comment: @Servy - I'm not sure what you're talking about, as there are no virtual methods here. In any case, I think refactoring to avoid hiding is a better solution.